# Add widget fade effect on images switching

Tags: android, android-widget

I have home screen widget that shows images. Images are switching for some scenario. I need to add fade effect on images switching. Is it some way to do it?

I know how to use animation for my purpose on View, but AppWidget uses RemoteViews...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no ordinary thing to do that. The only thing you can do - use bitmap alpha channel for fadding image, but it takes all processor time. My advice - do not do that.